# Views information not bolding used templates

Tags: views, theming

The templates used in my views are not bolded (template information). I do not know if this due to a module interaction.I have checked with different administration themes but does not show up anything.I would like to know how to get back this valuable information.

I have also tried an alternative solution that did not work. I have enabled the theme debug mode, and looked for the template used in the source code. It show the default template while i have a another (specific) one.

I have been looking around without any success!

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Sounds like you're using Drupal 7?

Comment: yas i did clear the cache and i registry so many times. I am using the latest of D7 and the latestest of views module

Comment: While it's not bolded, does the template get used or not? Did u double check the template name? Did u place template inside ur there's folder in /sites/all/themes/YourTheme/templates folder?

Comment: Yes i have picked a template name from the "template information", created a new file with that name and inserted some texte.I cleared the cache many times and registry as well. I am also using theme debug option to see if it is detected but does not recognize it.

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: in the template folder of the used theme

Comment: Sounds like ur doing everything correctly, are u sure ur uploading the template file to the correct server?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the issue. I was using Role theme switcher and i have selected a new theme to test it. It seems that this does not work well with my production theme, and this conflict between themes makes the views template bug. 
I have disabled one of the themes and it works. 
Thanks for your time